# ssis 2012: dynamic connection to flat file and database server from a table

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, flat-file, ssis-2012

Our Application server and the database server resided on the same box in the past, but they now they have been separated.I would like my connection managers to be dynamic enough to connect to the 'test database server' for processing the data from files that reside on the 'test App server'.
For Eg: If @@Servername='TestSvrDb' then all the data files need to be read from 'TestSvrApp'. Can I please have two examples to be able to connect the database and the flat file using a table definition? thank you all so much

Comment: Use environment variables in case you have a SSIS catalog in place.

Comment: Have you searched google? http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables